# SVM as a last layer of a CNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, svm

I am new to the community and I am trying to learn as much as possible but I came to a point where I need help because I don't manage to find the right solution.

I have a CNN with a softmax layer at the end but I would like to have an SVM and I really don't know how to do it. I found something online saying that basically, I have to change from softmax to linear but I don't understand why and since I don't understand I can not do it.

If anyone knows how to do it please can you let me know how to do it with the code below? Thank you and sorry if this question was asked before or if you find it not that smart. I am new to this.

Code below:

```
    model = keras.models.Sequential([    
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,channels)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
    
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
    
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
    
    keras.layers.Dense(43, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: you could extract 2D feature representations from your pre-trained neural network and use them as input for your SVM (transfer learning)

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself. My question is how to do the SVM as last layer

Comment: Simply not possible

Comment: So with the phrase above, I wanted to do the following. extract the features and use them as input for my SVM instead of going forward with the CNN and giving in input to the fully connected neural network.  that is possible because you already suggested that. My question is once I extracted the feature which is not hard since I already did that.  How can I build the SVM in order to link my features? This is what I would like to know.

Comment: once u extracted the feature you can simply call my_svm.fit(my_extracted_feat, y) like any standard svm model fit. Pay only attention to extract 2D features in order to be used in sklearn models

Comment: Ah ok this is what I was looking for. Thank you. I thought I have to do some more complicated things. Amazing. You have my upvote.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any layers after a flatten layer.Now use this model to extract a feature vector for xtrain and xtest for svm .
Refer: YouTube channel digitalsreeni

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).